# R Studio: Change cursor color

Tags: rstudio, mouse-cursor

I use the Cobalt editor theme in R Studio which I have slightly adjusted by changing the respective .cache.css file. The background color is dark (my choice) but the text cursor (mouse pointer) is dark as well so it is hard to see. 
Where or how can I change the the mouse pointer color to e.g. green in the .cache.css file?

Answer (score 2):

Using [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1045) on another tool, I added these lines to my `cache.css` file:

```css
.ace_editor *, input.GNKRCKGCKS { cursor: -webkit-image-set(url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAL0lEQVQoz2NgCD3x//9/BhBYBWdhgFVAiVW4JBFKGIa4AqD0//9D3pt4I4tAdAMAHTQ/j5Zom30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 1x, url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAAz0lEQVRIx2NgYGBY/R8I/vx5eelX3n82IJ9FxGf6tksvf/8FiTMQAcAGQMDvSwu09abffY8QYSAScNk45G198eX//yev73/4///701eh//kZSARckrNBRvz//+8+6ZohwCzjGNjdgQxkAg7B9WADeBjIBqtJCbhRA0YNoIkBSNmaPEMoNmA0FkYNoFKhapJ6FGyAH3nauaSmPfwI0v/3OukVi0CIZ+F25KrtYcx/CTIy0e+rC7R1Z4KMICVTQQ14feVXIbR695u14+Ir4gwAAD49E54wc1kWAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 2x) 5 8, text; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Solution**

You can edit specific themes by going to 'C://Program Files/RStudio/resources/themes/your_theme_of_chocie'

Open the file, for example `cobalt.rstheme` with something like VS code

Paste the line as supplied by @Devin from above answer.

Save the file and re-open RStudio. While this is a .rstheme file, it is written in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find way to edit `cache.css` but following from Devin's reply and rstudio forum worked on my end.

```
cd <path_to_rstudio_server>/www/rstudio/
nano 1C0010BF6F4789B46E4091CEC24E6DAD.cache.css
```

where **1C0010BF6F4789B46E4091CEC24E6DAD.cache.css** matched current *Material* theme I am using for rstudio. To view css file for your rstudio theme, right-click anywhere in the upper code panel in rstudio browser window and select *Inspect (Element)* option for Chrome (Firefox). Under *Styles* section on right panel, you should see file name ~ `alphanumberic_characters.cache.css`.

Add cursor css from Devin's reply under `.ace_string.ace_regexp`:

```
.ace_cursor,
    .ace_string.ace_regexp {
      color: #D30102
      -webkit-image-set(url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAL0lEQVQoz2NgCD3x//9/BhBYBWdhgFVAiVW4JBFKGIa4AqD0//9D3pt4I4tAdAMAHTQ/j5Zom30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 1x, url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAAz0lEQVRIx2NgYGBY/R8I/vx5eelX3n82IJ9FxGf6tksvf/8FiTMQAcAGQMDvSwu09abffY8QYSAScNk45G198eX//yev73/4///701eh//kZSARckrNBRvz//+8+6ZohwCzjGNjdgQxkAg7B9WADeBjIBqtJCbhRA0YNoIkBSNmaPEMoNmA0FkYNoFKhapJ6FGyAH3nauaSmPfwI0v/3OukVi0CIZ+F25KrtYcx/CTIy0e+rC7R1Z4KMICVTQQ14feVXIbR695u14+Ir4gwAAD49E54wc1kWAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 2x) 5 8, text;
    }
```

Save, exit and restart rstudio-server to take edits into effect.

Comment: I only see `.ace_constant.ace_other,
.ace_cursor {
  color: #CCCCCC
}`