# How to change the colour of the cursor in RStudio terminal?

Tags: themes, rstudio

I'm pretty annoyed that the colour of the cursor that indicates where you are in the terminal is black against a dark grey background when you use a dark theme. It's just hard to see where in the text you are, see example below:

[image]

I've tried to change this without succes. The theme I'm using is the [Chaos](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/resources/themes/chaos.rstheme) theme, which is a standard theme that I think comes with every RStudio distribution. In the file linked above, I've tried changing the following (L191-L194) from this:

```
.terminal.xterm-cursor-style-block.focus:not(.xterm-cursor-blink-on) .terminal-cursor {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}
```

to this:

```
.terminal.xterm-cursor-style-block.focus:not(.xterm-cursor-blink-on) .terminal-cursor {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #FCE94F;
}
```

After saving the edited file as `chaos2.rsthemes` and using the Tools > Global options > Appearance > Add... in RStudio to add the new document as a theme. I saw no change in the cursor colour after rebooting RStudio, whereas I had hoped it became yellow.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941467/r-studio-change-cursor-color) talks about the mouse cursor instead of the text cursor I want to edit.

Does anyone know what the correct way to edit the theme is so I can have a light terminal cursor on a dark grey background? I don't want to change to a totally different theme, I just want this one small change.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243172/how-to-change-rgb-colors-in-git-bash-for-windows#:~:text=Click%20on%20the%20upper%20left,Go%20to%20tab%20%22Colors%22) works to change the cursor to i.e. an orange | for the regular git bash shell. But, for some reason unknown to me, *RStudio* displays the old format (black block) despite having the same `echo $0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I admit that it is quite tricky to achieve because the cursor colour is made of two elements one doesn't work without the other.

So what you need to add is `.normal-mode .ace_cursor` block in addition to `.ace_cursor`. Chaos theme has `.ace_cursor` only and changing the color value won't change anything.

In order to do that correctly, follow the steps below:

1. Open RStudio and go to Tools > Global options > Appearance; and choose another theme, then close RStudio.
2. Now you need to go to the themes folder

   **Windows:** Program Files > RStudio > resources > themes

   **MacOS:** Applications > RStudio > Contents > Resources > resources > themes
3. Cut `chaos.rstheme` to your desktop and open it with Notepad or your favourite editor. (Don't forget to keep a backup)
4. Find `.ace_cursor` block below

```
.ace_cursor {
  border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

and replace it with these two blocks

```
.ace_cursor {
  color: #FCE94F;
}
.normal-mode .ace_cursor {
  background-color: #FCE94F;
}
```

and save the changes.

5. Now open RStudio and go to Tools > Global options > Appearance, under **Editor theme** click **Add** and choose `chaos.rstheme` you edited on your Desktop.
6. Click **Apply** and you should see the new cursor colour with the Chaos theme.